# Add recursive function to class as member

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm having trouble adding a recursive function to a class.

I can declare the function private no problem above my member declarations using let.

But when I try to make it public using member, it does not compile.

```
member this.rec mux xs ys =
  match xs with
  | [] -> ys
  | x::xt -> x :: mux ys xt
```

Thanks for correcting me and pointing me to a proper resource online. I have been reading many tutorials but I can't find this info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Member functions are always recursive, no `rec` keyword required:

```
member this.mux xs ys =
```

(and even if there was a `rec` keyword, it would go before `this`, same way as `private` - `member rec this.mux ...`)

But once you've declared it as a member, you have to reference it as a member as well - i.e. `this.mux` instead of `mux`:

```
member this.mux xs ys =
  match xs with
  | [] -> ys
  | x::xt -> x :: this.mux ys xt
```

---

### Why member functions are always recursive, while let-bound functions are not

(in response to comment)

`let`-bound functions can shadow previously defined identifiers. For example:

```
let f x = x+5
let f x = x-2
let a = f 5   // a = 3, not 10
```

This is a perfectly legal thing to do (except at top level in modules), and is frequently used for utilitarian purposes, e.g. sanitizing parameters:

```
let sendEmail email subject body =
   let email = canonicalize email
   ...
```

Notice how in this function the first thing I do is clean up the email, and then proceed to do whatever (NOTE: this is not "assigning" new value to the parameter `email`, but defining a whole new value that just happens to have the same name).

This new definition of `email` is used in the rest of the function instead of the original parameter `email`. This is called "shadowing".

Now, notice how this new definition of `email` references the old definition of `email`. This is only possible because `email` is not recursive: the compiler knows that the word `email` within the definition of `email` refers to the previously defined value, not the one being defined right now.

"But wait" - you say - "what does it even mean for `email` to be recursive? Doesn't the term "recursive" only apply to functions?". Well, no. Values can be recursive too, but that's a topic for another time. For now, here's a different example:

```
let notifyUsers sendEmail log =
   let sendEmail name =
      log ("Notifying " + name)
      sendEmail (name + "@contoso.com")

   sendEmail "John"
   sendEmail "Mark"
   sendEmail "Matthew"
   sendEmail "Luke"
```

In this example, I "shadowed" the function `sendEmail` with a new definition that logs the name of the user before calling the original `sendEmail`. If I defined my "new" `sendEmail` as recursive (i.e. `let rec sendEmail name = ...`), this program would result in an infinite loop: the function would just endlessly call itself. But because the function is not recursive, it is able to reference previously-defined value of the same name.

Member functions don't have this problem: you can't shadow a class method, that would be meaningless.

This problem is addressed differently in different languages.
For example, in languages with everything mutable by default, this problem doesn't arise at all: you just mutate the values and that's it... Unless you want to change the type, too - then you're screwed.
For another example, in Haskell, all values are always recursive, and shadowing will cause a warning. As a result, people are forced to [use ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642430/avoid-temporary-variables-by-using-name-shadowing) or get creative with naming, or even introduce a monad where none is required.

Comment: That solved it. My issue was that I wasn't referencing it as this.mux in the logic (last line). Just for learning, is there a reason why member functions are always recursive while private functions (with let) are not necessarily?

Comment: That's kind of a subtle question with no clear justification one way or another. The short answer is: name shadowing. For the long answer, I updated the original answer.

Comment: @happyD: That's part of F#'s historical baggage. It's not a homogeneous language, rather it's two languages in a single package - a higher-level functional language derived from OCaml (`let`, `let rec`) and a lower-level language that more closely matches the native .NET constructs (`member this.X`). Those two languages come from lineages that took different positions on how to express self-reference a long time ago, and F# retains this difference rather than trying to reconcile it.

Comment: @happyD: In particular, this answer describes the historical background of why let-bound functions are not recursive by default in F# - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1891573/679898